# How to get user profile information from Facebook API Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get user profile information Facebook. Begins loading, I click to confirm permission to send my profile, again, continue loading but eventually get empty fields.

What am I doing wrong? Help please.

```
public class SettingsApps extends Activity {
public final String API_KEY = "492429660800628";
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(API_KEY);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.settings);

mPrefs=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String acces_token=mPrefs.getString("acces_token",null);
long expires=mPrefs.getLong("acces_expires", 0);

if (Session.getActiveSession() == null || Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new StatusCallback() { 
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("State= " + state);

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                System.out.println("Token=" + session.getAccessToken());
                Request request =  Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {       
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {                                

                                if (user != null) {
                                    TextView idText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id);
                                    TextView first_nameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
                                    TextView last_nameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.last_name);
                                    idText.setText(user.getId());
                                    first_nameText.setText(user.getFirstName());
                                    last_nameText.setText(user.getLastName());
                                }
                                if (response != null) {
                                    System.out.println("Response="  + response);
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsApps.this, response.toString(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
            }
            if (exception != null) {
                System.out.println("Some thing bad happened!");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}   
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
}
```

LogCat

```
669: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.fitness_sport_betta/.SettingsApps } from pid 847
899: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Starting: Intent { act=SSO_WITH_FALLBACK cmp=com.fitness_sport_betta/com.facebook.LoginActivity (has extras) } from pid 847
949: INFO/System.out(847): State= OPENING
539: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Displayed com.fitness_sport_betta/com.facebook.LoginActivity: +621ms (total +851ms)
669: DEBUG/dalvikvm(389): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1685K, 41% free 6996K/11783K, external 716K/1038K, paused 16ms+11ms
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389): Exception during service
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389): com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id 
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:74)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:103)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:184)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:267)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:28)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.SingleMethodRunner.a(SingleMethodRunner.java:125)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:274)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:175)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:214)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:37)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue$3.run(OrcaServiceQueue.java:168)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
420: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
459: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Starting: Intent { act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_ACTIVITY cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] cmp=com.facebook.katana/.platform.PlatformActivity (has extras) } from pid 847
639: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.facebook.katana/.platform.PlatformWrapperActivity (has extras) } from pid 389
670: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Displayed com.facebook.katana/.platform.PlatformActivity: +1s87ms
779: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Displayed com.facebook.katana/.platform.PlatformWrapperActivity: +1s106ms
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389): Exception during service
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389): com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id 
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:74)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:103)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:184)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:267)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:28)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.SingleMethodRunner.a(SingleMethodRunner.java:125)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:274)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:175)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:214)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:37)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue$3.run(OrcaServiceQueue.java:168)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
449: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(389):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389): Failed to send
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389): com.facebook.orca.ops.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:597)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:38)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation$2.run(OrcaServiceOperation.java:562)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
469: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(389):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
009: WARN/InputManagerService(72): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40677138 (uid=10030 pid=847)
009: WARN/InputManagerService(72): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40556e88
529: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Displayed com.fitness_sport_betta/.SettingsApps: +10s839ms
```

Last change:

```
public class SettingsApps extends Activity {

public final String API_KEY = "492429660800628";
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(API_KEY);
public final String[] permissions = {"publish_stream"};
String mUserId;
String mUserToken;
String mUserName;
String mUserEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.settings);

if (Session.getActiveSession() == null || Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new StatusCallback() { 
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("State= " + state);
            authorizeAndPostMassage(); 
            if (exception != null) {
                System.out.println("Some thing bad happened!");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}

public void authorizeAndPostMassage() {

    facebook.authorize(this, permissions, new DialogListener () {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                Toast.makeText(SettingsApps.this, "Authorization successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getProfileInformation();    
        }       
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            Toast.makeText(SettingsApps.this, "Facebook error, try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        }       
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Toast.makeText(SettingsApps.this, "Error, try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
        }       
        public void onCancel() {
            //Этот коллбэк никогда не срабатывает, вероятно, ошибка в SDK
            Toast.makeText(SettingsApps.this, "Authorization canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                         
        }});        
}

public void getProfileInformation() {
    try {

        JSONObject profile = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me"));
        Log.e("Profile", "" + profile);

        mUserId = profile.getString("id");
        mUserToken = facebook.getAccessToken();
        mUserName = profile.getString("name");
        mUserEmail = profile.getString("email");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.v("FaceBook_Profile",""+mUserId+"\n"+mUserToken+"\n"+mUserName+"\n"+mUserEmail);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Name: " + mUserName + "\nEmail: " + mUserEmail,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    } catch (FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This code for facebook SDK 3.0
It`s works!

```
public class FacebookInfo extends Activity {
...
String get_id, get_name, get_gender, get_email, get_birthday, get_locale, get_location;

private Session.StatusCallback fbStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        // do something with <response> now
                        try{
                            get_id = user.getId();
                            get_name = user.getName();
                            get_gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");
                            get_email = (String) user.getProperty("email");
                            get_birthday = user.getBirthday();
                            get_locale = (String) user.getProperty("locale");
                            get_location = user.getLocation().toString();   

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, user.getId() + "; " +  
                            user.getName() + "; " +
                            (String) user.getProperty("gender") + "; " +        
                            (String) user.getProperty("email") + "; " +
                            user.getBirthday()+ "; " +
                            (String) user.getProperty("locale") + "; " +
                            user.getLocation());
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception e");
                         }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
...
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fbinfo);
    try {
        openActiveSession(this, true, fbStatusCallback, Arrays.asList(
                new String[] { "email",  "user_location", "user_birthday",
 "user_likes", "publish_actions" }), savedInstanceState);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  private  Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI,
 StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity).
setPermissions(permissions).setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.
SSO_WITH_FALLBACK).setCallback(callback).
setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + session);
    if (session == null) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, fbStatusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED) || allowLoginUI) {
            session.openForRead(openRequest);
            return session;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Comment: user returns always null So can u please suggest me why

Comment: @Roman Can you please provide whole code for getting user profile data.

Comment: Request.executeMeRequestAsync is deprecated, so from now you have to use Request.newMeRequest, see my answer below

Comment: @Roman Why I get error in Session.StatusCallback??  It says that this class does not exist ...

Comment: Could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275629/facebook-sdk-for-android-graphuser Similar to this, but other permissions. I have tried, but have problems accessing the required details

Comment: can we store that data into databse?

Answer (score 7):

Request.executeMeRequestAsync is deprecated! So, do like this:

Once your session ready:

```
private void getUserData(Session session, SessionState state)
{
    if (state.isOpened())
    {
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        String name = user.getName();
                        // If you asked for email permission
                        String email = (String) user.getProperty("email");
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Name: " + name + " Email: " + email);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception e");
                    }

                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get some bugs because some classes like SessionState or GraphUser "cannot be resolved to a type" ... or because "The type com.facebook.login.LoginClient is not visible" ... How I can solve it?

Answer (score 3):

```
//register callback object for facebook result
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            //By Profile Class
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if (profile != null) {
                facebook_id=profile.getId();
                f_name=profile.getFirstName();
                m_name=profile.getMiddleName();
                l_name=profile.getLastName();
                full_name=profile.getName();
                profile_image=profile.getProfilePictureUri(400, 400).toString();
            }
            //Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this,"Wait...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                email_id=object.getString("email");
                                gender=object.getString("gender");
                                String profile_name=object.getString("name");
                                long fb_id=object.getLong("id"); //use this for logout

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                //  e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    });

            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this,getResources().getString(R.string.login_canceled_facebooklogin),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this,getResources().getString(R.string.login_failed_facebooklogin),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

first create object and veriable for facebook:

```
private static String FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "492429660800628";
private Facebook facebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
```

after OnCreate Method :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

    facebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    loginFacebook();//this method when called when you required..

}



private void loginFacebook() {

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream",
                "read_stream" }, new LoginDialogListener());

    } else {

        getProfileInformation();

    }

}



class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        try {

            getProfileInformation();

        } catch (Exception error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

please try this method after login facebook:

```
public void getProfileInformation() {


    try {

        JSONObject profile = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me"));
        Log.e("Profile", "" + profile);

        mUserId = profile.getString("id");
        mUserToken = facebook.getAccessToken();
        mUserName = profile.getString("name");
        mUserEmail = profile.getString("email");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Log.e("FaceBook_Profile",""+mUserId+"\n"+mUserToken+"\n"+mUserName+"\n"+mUserEmail);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Name: " + mUserName + "\nEmail: " + mUserEmail,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }

        });

    } catch (FacebookError e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Forgive my  illiteracy, but I do not know exactly where to insert the code. I am for the last four days pereprobyval a dozen codes. I understand that it should work, but I have not come out.

Comment: Yes, I installed the facebook sdk, and I can go on my page.

Comment: ok so are you sure you login after get facebook response in JSON?

Comment: are you using latest facebook android SDK??

Comment: yes, with session, that [Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/android/downloads/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22321/discussion-between-mahesh-kavathiya-and-roman)

Comment: Your code generated an error "FacebookError Something went wrong. Please try again." :(

Comment: Guys what if i want the method getProfileInformation() to be in another activity not in the same activity how can i accomplish this if the user's session is saved in shared preference i need to load his stuff in different activity. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using facebook sdk 4.3.0 today and there is no any suggestion for `private Facebook facebook;` I added the module very well. but not able to import the facebook package.

Comment: i am done with login but i want to get user data too. that i don't know what to do? @MaheshKavathiya . Whenever i open app->click loginbtn->fill detail->click login in facebook login dialog now i want to take the user detail for my profile creation of the app. how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

First: login

```
LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookLoginCallback());
```

Then: get profile infomation

```
// call this when login success
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
// getAvatar
String avatar = ImageRequest.getProfilePictureUri(profile.getId(), width, height).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! for quick snippets

Answer (score 1):

For those who's still struggling in new Graph API 3.0 here's the solution works for Graph API 2.12 or below.

```
  //Request a read permission of user's info from Facebook
    //Data provided by Facebook will be used for Firebase FireStore
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LogIn.this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

            mStateOfSuccess = false;
            //Dismiss any snackbar first before showing a new one
            mSnackBar.dismiss();
            mSnackBar.show();

            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);

            //Bundle is use for passing data as K/V pair like a Map
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            //Fields is the key of bundle with values that matched the proper Permissions Reference provided by Facebook
            bundle.putString("fields","id, email, first_name, last_name, gender,age_range");

            //Graph API to access the data of user's facebook account
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("Login Success", response.toString());

                            //For safety measure enclose the request with try and catch
                            try {

                                //The get() or getString() key should be included in Bundle otherwise it won't work properly
                                //If not then error dialog will be called

                                //First re-initialize jSON object to a new Contructor with parameter that is equal to a jSON format age range
                                JSONObject ageRange  = new JSONObject(object.getString("age_range"));

                                        //Log in using Facebook with Firebase
                                        loginToFirebaseUsingFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken()
                                                ,object.getString("first_name")
                                                ,object.getString("last_name")
                                                //Then get again get a string from object itself for the minimum age range
                                                //The idea is that we need to get minimum age only written in string format
                                                //not the whole age range data that is written in jSON format
                                                ,ageRange.getString("min")
                                                ,object.getString("gender")
                                                ,object.getString("email")
                                        );

                            }
                            //If no data has been retrieve throw some error
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                               ErrorDialog(e.getMessage(),"facebookAuth");
                            }

                        }
                    });


            //Set the bundle's data as Graph's object data
            request.setParameters(bundle);

            //Execute this Graph request asynchronously
            request.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            ErrorDialog("Request has canceled.","facebookAuth");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            ErrorDialog(String.valueOf(error),"facebookAuth");
        }
    });


}
```

Note that using age range requires App Review if will use in the production, meaning you may just try to use this on your own account (admin or developers account). Visit: **https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/?locale=en_US#reference-public_profile** for more details.