# How to get user basic info from FaceBook SDK in android?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to get the user info from FaceBook using FaceBook sdk in android.

I was able o login successfully. I am trying to get the user info from answer provided in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195468/1662775.) and I am getting the following error.

Please provide how to go further from here.
[image]

I did not any error for the first time but I am getting the above error from the second time onwards.

Comment: your hash key is not matched with which you stored in facebook developer page.

Comment: Hey I got the answer ofcourse with help of the stackoverflow itself. I have taken the SHA1 ey from Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->Android->Build. I have converted the SHA1 key into Key Hash from the following site. http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en . There is a slight mismatch in the key that got generated and the key which I got from convering SHA1. So I tried replacing it in the facebook developer and the app is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you have forgot to include your hashkey in facebook developer page of your app. Try this code in onCreate of your Activity to get your Hashkey

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.example.packagename", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

the KehHash is generated in the logcat and you should copy and paste that in facebook developer page of your app.Also don't forget to use correct app_id in your project.
Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash) for more info.